# Slow table loading

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

After I uninstalled Oracle 11g and installed Oracle 12c I have a problem with table loading in the left tree menu in SQL Developer. I took no more than one second before and now it takes a few minutes. Do you have any idea where could be the problem?

The only thing that I have found is that the problem is probably in this query

```
select * from (
  SELECT o.OBJECT_NAME, o.OBJECT_ID ,'' short_name, decode(bitand(t.property, 32), 32, 'YES', 'NO') partitioned,
                decode(bitand(t.property, 64), 64, 'IOT',
               decode(bitand(t.property, 512), 512, 'IOT_OVERFLOW',
               decode(bitand(t.flags, 536870912), 536870912, 'IOT_MAPPING', null))) iot_type, 
         o.OWNER OBJECT_OWNER, o.CREATED, o.LAST_DDL_TIME, O.GENERATED, O.TEMPORARY, case when xt.obj# is null then 'N' else 'Y' end EXTERNAL
    FROM SYS.Dba_OBJECTS O ,sys.tab$ t, sys.external_tab$ xt
    WHERE O.OWNER = :SCHEMA
    and   o.object_id = t.obj#(+)
    and   o.object_id = xt.obj#(+)
    AND O.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' 
union all
SELECT OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_ID , syn.SYNONYM_NAME short_NAME, decode(bitand(t.property, 32), 32, 'YES', 'NO') partitioned,
                decode(bitand(t.property, 64), 64, 'IOT',
               decode(bitand(t.property, 512), 512, 'IOT_OVERFLOW',
               decode(bitand(t.flags, 536870912), 536870912, 'IOT_MAPPING', null))) iot_type, 
       SYN.TABLE_OWNER OBJECT_OWNER, o.CREATED, o.LAST_DDL_TIME, O.GENERATED, O.TEMPORARY, case when xt.obj# is null then 'N' else 'Y' end EXTERNAL
              FROM SYS.Dba_OBJECTS O, sys.user_synonyms syn,sys.tab$ t, sys.external_tab$ xt
              WHERE  syn.table_owner = o.owner
              and    syn.TABLE_NAME = o.object_NAME
              and    o.object_id = t.obj#
              and   o.object_id = xt.obj#(+)
              and    o.object_type = 'TABLE'
              and    :INCLUDE_SYNS = 1
)
 WHERE /**/OBJECT_NAME NOT IN (SELECT OBJECT_NAME FROM RECYCLEBIN)
                         AND not object_name like 'BIN$%'
```

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Make sure your data dictionary stats are fresh...

Comment: SQL> EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_DICTIONARY_STATS;

Answer (score 1):

Thank for your answers. I figure it out by purging recycle bin. Loading tables was slow because of this part of the statement

> WHERE /**/OBJECT_NAME NOT IN (SELECT OBJECT_NAME FROM RECYCLEBIN) AND
>   not object_name like 'BIN$%'

Answer (score 0):

Using `NOT EXISTS` is mostly better than `NOT IN` from the performance point of view. You can try the following query made up of modern syntax with

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                     FROM RECYCLEBIN 
                    WHERE OBJECT_NAME = oo.OBJECT_NAME 
                       OR OBJECT_NAME LIKE 'BIN$%' )
```

condition taken into one subquery :

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT o.OBJECT_NAME,
               o.OBJECT_ID,
               '' short_name,
               decode(bitand(t.property, 32), 32, 'YES', 'NO') partitioned,
               decode(bitand(t.property, 64),
                      64,
                      'IOT',
                      decode(bitand(t.property, 512),
                             512,
                             'IOT_OVERFLOW',
                             decode(bitand(t.flags, 536870912),
                                    536870912,
                                    'IOT_MAPPING',
                                    null))) iot_type,
               o.OWNER OBJECT_OWNER,
               o.CREATED,
               o.LAST_DDL_TIME,
               O.GENERATED,
               O.TEMPORARY,
               case
                 when xt.obj# is null then
                  'N'
                 else
                  'Y'
               end EXTERNAL
          FROM SYS.DBA_OBJECTS O
          LEFT JOIN sys.tab$ t ON o.object_id = t.obj#
          LEFT JOIN sys.external_tab$ xt ON o.object_id = xt.obj#
         WHERE O.OWNER = :SCHEMA
           AND O.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'       
        UNION ALL
        SELECT OBJECT_NAME,
               OBJECT_ID,
               syn.SYNONYM_NAME short_NAME,
               decode(bitand(t.property, 32), 32, 'YES', 'NO') partitioned,
               decode(bitand(t.property, 64),
                      64,
                      'IOT',
                      decode(bitand(t.property, 512),
                             512,
                             'IOT_OVERFLOW',
                             decode(bitand(t.flags, 536870912),
                                    536870912,
                                    'IOT_MAPPING',
                                    null))) iot_type,
               SYN.TABLE_OWNER OBJECT_OWNER,
               o.CREATED,
               o.LAST_DDL_TIME,
               O.GENERATED,
               O.TEMPORARY,
               case
                 when xt.obj# is null then
                  'N'
                 else
                  'Y'
               end EXTERNAL
          FROM SYS.DBA_OBJECTS O
          JOIN sys.user_synonyms syn ON syn.TABLE_NAME = o.object_NAME
          JOIN sys.tab$ t ON o.object_id = t.obj#       
          LEFT JOIN sys.external_tab$ xt ON o.object_id = xt.obj# 
         WHERE syn.table_owner = o.owner 
           AND o.object_type = 'TABLE'
           AND :INCLUDE_SYNS = 1 
           ) oo
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM RECYCLEBIN WHERE OBJECT_NAME = oo.OBJECT_NAME OR OBJECT_NAME LIKE 'BIN$%' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it still takes a few minutes to execute. Also, the sql is generated by SQL developer so I cant probably edit it.

Comment: you're welcome @MichalRubas try to call again, in the first call system loses during the parse step.

Comment: *"Using NOT EXISTS is mostly better than NOT IN from the performance point of view."* Citation needed. Which is better depends on the relative size of the result sets of the outer and sub queries. And of course whether the subquery will return null values. Given that this query was written by Oracle's own developers I would like to think they made the correct choice.